# onClick methods in an AlertDialog.Builder don't seem to be triggering

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have the following alert dialog being built:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ... /*Code to initialize intent*/

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.launch_preference);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.term_preference, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchTerm");
                dialog.cancel();
                try { startActivity(intent); }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { showUpdateError(); }
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.xterm_preference, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                intent.putExtra("launchType", "launchXTerm");
                dialog.cancel();
                try { startActivity(intent); }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { showUpdateError(); }
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
}

private void showUpdateError() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("myApp is attempting to launch myOtherApp. It is either missing or out of date Please update it and try again.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Got it!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

Running this activity causes the alert dialog to appear, but clicking either of its button just causes the app to close.

I'm migrating a family of apps to a new ecosystem using a new type of intent to communicate between them. The idea is that if myOtherApp hasn't been updated, the second alert dialog will appear after the first disappears. Unfortunately, the onClick methods aren't even entered during debug mode.

Comment: Just remove finish() from onClick()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the dialog after you start the activity. Remove finish(), which simply kills your activity.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was doing wrong. I feel like finish in an important piece, but I think I'm misunderstanding its use. I want this app (which is just a launcher) to be killed after the execution flow of these buttons is completed. Is calling finish() not the correct way to go about that?

Comment: In that case, you call finish() after you showed your dialog. You can't kill your activity and expect to do things in it. I highly recommend you read the activity life-cycle from the docs. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I feel like I have a firm enough understanding of the life-cycle for what I'm trying to accomplish. The area that I'm lacking understanding in is how much Android takes advantage of concurrency. For example, if I put finish() after builder.create().show(), won't it kill the app before (as) it displays the button?

Answer (score 0):

Put finish() into try{} clause instead of after it;

```
try { startActivity(intent); finish()}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be helping. Breakpoints in the onClick methods still aren't being hit, and the behavior hasn't changed.